# Euler Approximation of General ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a slightly general question that might be related to the Euler Approximation of ODE solution, could someone provide some thoughts on this or share some source could potentially helpful?

Consider the differential equation $$dY_t = f(Y_t)dX_t$$ on time $t\in[0,1]$. We cut the inteval to $m\in\mathbb{N}$ equal length subintervals, and define the solution $Y^m(t)$ satisfies $$Y^m_t = Y^m_{\frac{k}{m}} + f(Y^m_{\frac{k}{m}})(X_t-X_{\frac{k}{m}})\text{ for }t\in[\frac{k}{m}, \frac{k+1}{m})$$This could be understood as locking the coefficient on those intervals as the value on their left endpoints.

If we perturb the driven function $X_t$, and treat the operator $F^m$ such that $F^m(X_t) = Y^m_t$, this operator is continuous(could be more rigorous defined in various settings, e.g, if $X_t$ is smooth enough, then $F_m$ could be continuous in the uniform topology, or say for general X_t with jumps, we might consider Skorohod topology)

Now we have the fixed $f$, and a sequence of solution operator $F^m$. At a fixed $X_t$, could we have some result such as $F^m$ is uniformly continuous at $X_t$? In other words, for $\forall\epsilon >0$, could we find a $\delta>0$, such that $d(X'_t, X_t) < \delta$ implies $d(F^m(X'_t), F^m(X_t)) < \epsilon$ with this choosen of $\delta$ independent of $m$?

Again, I raise this slight general question and concede that the description above is not rigorous enough for any detailed discussion. It would be really helpful to me if you could mention some textbooks or papers that this type of question is discussed. Really appreciated!